# Не передается переменная в контроллер из формы (laravel)

Tags: laravel

Не передается переменная из формы в контроллер. *dd()* показывает, что переменная ничего не получает.

Код из шаблона:

```
<form action="{{ route('setTopic'}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
@csrf            
<div class="select-box">
<label for="select-box1" class="label select-box1"><span class="label-desc">Choose topic</span></label><button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save</button>
<select id="select-box1" class="select" name="selectSetTopic">
@foreach($dataCategories  as $topic)
<option value="{{$topic->id}}">{{ $topic->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

Код из контроллера:

```
public function setTopic(Request $selectSetTopic) {
dd($selectSetTopic);
return redirect()->route('post')->with('success', 'Ok!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 у вас не хватает скобки в строке
`<form action="{{ route('setTopic'}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`      необходимо:
`<form action="{{ route('setTopic')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
2. В контроллере:

```php
public function setTopic(Request $request) {
$selectSetTopic = $request->selectSetTopic;
// или вот так $request->input('selectSetTopic') или так $request->get('selectSetTopic')

dd($selectSetTopic);
return redirect()->route('post')->with('success', 'Ok!');
}
```